# Sending a notification crashes app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a react-native app, and I thoroughly followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message) to add Firebase to your app, and Add the SDK.

However, when I try to send my first notification using the Notification composer, my application simply crashes with the message "pushNotif has stopped working". This happenes regardless of background or foreground state.

Has anyone ever experienced this? does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) to implement FCM in react-native, then you'll be able to handle notifications in your react-native javascript code.

Comment: Yes I appreciate the response, I have tried both react-native-fcm and react-native-push-notifications, following their instructions. This doesn't change the fact the app crashes when I send a notification :(

Comment: There's some native ios and android configuration to do, i remember having some difficulty with ios, what device are you testing on ?

Comment: Android. Yes there is a fair bit of configuration, however I have done so and checked all of my steps quite a few times. Right now I'm creating a new project in android studio and trying again, trying to see if it's an isolated react-native issue.

Comment: I have tested a new project on android studio and it works like a charm, it must be something to do with react native setup. I'm trying to figure out what it could be.

Comment: I have actually managed to fix the issue somehow, by opening the react-native project's android folder, repeating the steps and most importantly syncing the gradle. This took me about a day to figure out.

Comment: Good job ! Thanks for accepting my answer btw, even if it didn't help that much.